# update svn repo weekly with changes from a git repository with losing history

Tags: git, svn, shell, cron, commit

i have a git repository which is my development Repository. I need to upload all changes on a weekly base to an svn repository - but I don't want to expose my git-commit-history. In other words: I explicit **want to lose** the history. All changes in the git repository for the given week need to be squashed to one single svn commit.

Example for one week:

Git:

```
commit 1 "fixed y"
commit 2 "added feature x"
commit 3 "foo"
commit 4 "fixed n"
```

SVN:

```
commit 1 "changes from this week"
```

Ideally it should be done by a small shell or python script which is started automatically via cron job.

I have the following variables:

```
LOCAL_PATH=/tmp/git-svn-bridge/
GIT_DIR=git_repo
SVN_DIR=svn_repo

GIT_REPO_URL=git://git@my_git_server
GIT_REPO_NAME=my_git_repo
GIT_REPO_BRANCH=master

SVN_REPO_URL=svn://my_svn_server
SVN_USER=FIXME
SVN_PASS=FIXME
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general idea - use `git archive` to export and then `rsync -a --delete` to update the svn working copy. Something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash -xue

gitdir='/path/to/git/repo-clone/'  
gitbranch='master'

svncodir='/path/to/svn/svn-checkout' 
svnrepo='file:///tmp/svnrepo'  # no trailing slash

# if svn checkout doesn't exit
[[ ! -d $svncodir ]] && svn co $svnrepo $svncodir

# if svn checkout is pointing to a different repo
if svn info $svncodir | grep -qF "URL: $svnrepo"; then
  rm -rf $svncodir
  svn co $svnrepo $svncodir
fi

tmpdest=$(mktemp -d)
git --git-dir $gitdir/.git archive $gitbranch | tar -x -C $tmpdest

cd $svncodir
svn update

# sync our temporary dir with the current svn checkout
rsync -av --delete --force --exclude '.svn' $tmpdest/ .
rm -rf $tmpdest/

# svn add new or modified files
svn add . --force --no-ignore

# remove missing ones (whitespace safe, unless you have
# files with 5 spaces in them)
svn status | awk -F' {5,}' '/!/ {print $2}' | xargs -I'{}' svn rm '{}'

svn status 
svn commit -m "changes from this week"
```